# Can a RxJava chain emit 2 items for a single event emission by its source observable?

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am trying to emit UI State based on an UIEvent. The UIEvent is a PublishSubject which feeds events into the following rx chain

```
private val speciesStateObservable:Observable<PokemonListViewState> = _uiEvents.observeOn(schedulers.io()).flatMap { uiEvent ->
    handleUIEvent(uiEvent)
}.scan(currentState) { previousState, newList ->
    val previousList = previousState.pokemonList as MutableList
    previousList.addAll(newList)
    Log.d("TAG", "${previousList.size}")
    previousState.copy(showLoading = false, pokemonList = previousList)
}.distinctUntilChanged().replay(1).doOnSubscribe {
    disposable.add(it)
}.doOnError {
    handleError(it)
}.doOnNext {
    //do some additional processing with this data
}
```

the `handleUIEvent` looks like this

```
    private fun handleUIEvent(uiEvent: UIEvent): Observable<List<PokemonSpecies>> {
    return when (uiEvent) {
        is UIEvent.FirstLoad -> fetchSpeciesUseCase.execute(currentPage).toObservable()
        is UIEvent.EndOfPage -> fetchSpeciesUseCase.execute(++currentPage).toObservable()
        is UIEvent.ItemClick -> Observable.just(currentState.pokemonList)
    }
}
```

this function makes the api call to fetch some data.

Now, for every UIEvent, I want the `speciesStateObservable:Observable<PokemonListViewState>` to emit a loading state first while the background fetching operation is in progress, and then emit the result state once the background operation is complete.

My state holder is

```
data class PokemonListViewState(val showLoading: Boolean, val pokemonList: List<PokemonSpecies>)
```

TL;DR

I want to emit 2 items for every one emission from source observable. First one being the loading state `PokemonListViewState(loading = true, items = mutableListOf())`
and second is the result state `PokemonListViewState(loading = false, items = listofitems)`

`scan` operator didn't help because it emits the initial state without executing the background operation inside `flatMap`, and I don't want to update the state inside `doOnNext` because i don't want to break the chain. Please help!!